# Sequencia de imagens e depois reset?

Tags: react, typescript

Estou a desenvolver um algoritmo para fazer uma imagem de fundo alterar sequencialmente e no fim voltar ao inicio, mas por algum motivo quando a sequencia acaba a pagina fica toda branca, sem qualquer tipo de erro na consola, alguém podia me ajudar?

```
type AuthListProps = {
    path: String
}[];
const [backgrounds, setBackgrounds] = useState<AuthListProps>(
    [
        {
            path: 'bg1.jpg',
        },
        {
            path: 'bg2.jpg'
        }
    ]
);
const [bgPosAtual, setBgPosAtual] = useState<number>(0);

useEffect(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        if(bgPosAtual === backgrounds.length-1){
            setBgPosAtual(0);
        }else{
            setBgPosAtual(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
        }
    }, 5000);
});

<BGWall bgPath={backgrounds[bgPosAtual].path} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), porque, com ele consegue utilizar dentro do efeitos colaterais quando a posição é atualizado e com isso o componente também seja atualizado. Nos efeitos colaterais é configurado que toda a alteração da variável `position` atualize o componente e/ou código referente seja também atualizado.

Com [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) o efeito não tem o controle e não sabe o momento que o componente é atualizado, então com [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) ele é executado, atualiza a variável e ai o `React` faz seu papel atualizando os componente(s);

```js
function Container(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <small>{props.title}</small>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={props.path} border="0" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState
  (
    [ 
      { title: 'Imagem 1', path: 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/native-american-teepee-grassy-plains-600w-1613143510.jpg'},
      { title: 'Imagem 2', path: 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/park-small-peoples-north-600w-796680427.jpg'},
    ]
  );
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(0);
  function loadImages() {
    setTimeout(() => {      
      if (position + 1 == images.length) {
        setPosition(state => 0);
      } else {
        setPosition(state => state + 1);        
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = loadImages();
    return () => clearTimeout(interval);
  }, [position]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Container 
        path={images[position].path} 
        title={images[position].title}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

**Referencia SO**<sup>En</sup>: [State not updating when using React state hook within setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval)