# Contador não atualiza com setInterval

Tags: react

no meu código tenho um useEffect que executa assim assim que o componente é montado, um setInterval, que  a cada um segundo chama a função incrementar que atualiza o contador , porém o contador nunca vai além de 1. Gostaria de saber o que esta acontecendo por trás dos panos para isso acontecer , desde já agradeço pela atenção[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Sequencia de imagens e depois reset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/548855/sequencia-de-imagens-e-depois-reset)

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 1):

Tem alguns problemas ai no seu código.

Primeiro, esse `setInterval` que você ta setando no `mount` do seu componente no objeto `window` não é uma boa, você perde o controle dele. Seria muito melhor que você usasse alguma coisa assim:

```
const interval = setInterval(incrementar, 1000);
```

Segundo, quando seu código executa pela primeira vez ele vai "construir" seu interval com o valor inicial do seu state, ao invés de usar

```
setCount(count + 1)
```

você deveria utilizar

```
setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
```

Isso vai fazer o contador sair do 1.

Terceiro, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) sobre `cleanup` do seu `useEffect` é uma boa quando você tiver utilizando interval você dar um `clearInterval` no retorno.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(increment, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Então pelo setInterval esta sendo executando quando o componente é montado, o incrementar nunca atualiza ?